# Eclipse console output not showing if some prints removed

Tags: c, eclipse, printing, output

This is incredible! I am running a C program on Eclipse. I have a lot of prints, but still not reaching the limit of 1MB (overall it's 64K text output, so no big deal).
Then I noticed that by adding more prints the console output was blank. I thought I had too many prints, but when removing some of them, the output was randomly behaving: for instance, if a print was removed, it didn't show up. Then I re-enabled that print, and removed another one, and the output was showing up.
Then I removed one more print, and the output was showing up some more information (like I reached its limit and I was freeing some space), but then I removed another more print, and mysteriously the output was blank again.

It is totally random, and it's not related to the MAX number of print (which, by the way, I set to unlimited). What really puzzles me it that if I REMOVE prints, sometime the output is not showing, which I can't really figure out why.

I also restart multiple times my machine, checked it is not running out of memory, and all the basic stuff I could think about, but nothing...
Has someone already seen this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this problem and never really found a good solution.  In the past restarting Eclipse has helped and I started putting fflush(NULL) in my code to flush all buffers.  I experienced this problem in Kepler but never in Luna.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your feedback. I'll add fflush(NULL) as well to see if it helps. Just tried, but no success....